# Flowplayer H.264 Video Encoding

Tags: h.264, flowplayer

I have encoded a video with H.264 using handbrake all the standard settings for "iPhone & iPod Touch" and enabling Optimize for Web as I have been told this adds metadata so the video can be streamed. This does seem to work, but I am getting no video, just audio. 
Here is the mp4 file in question.
http://c1592452.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/videos/36/original/deloitte.mp4

When played in quicktime it works fine, but flowplayer seems to have an issue with it. Am I encoding the video wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using RTMP you dont need to include the file name but you need to append mp4 to the start, so it'll look like

```
clip: 'mp4:/videos/36/original/deloitte'
```